# converting jdouble to double of type c

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

How can i convert `jdouble` of java type variable to `double` variable of type c ?

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to, it's just a typedef like so:

```
typedef double jdouble;
```

So no conversion is needed, once you have a `jdouble` you can treat it just as a `double`.

See for instance this [code example from Standford](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~naras/java/course/lec5/lec5.html#NWlec7-CodS-1):

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_Summer_sum__DD
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jdouble j1, jdouble j2) {
    return j1 + j2;
}
```

The addition is done directly with the `jdouble` values, trusting the compiler to figure out how to generate the required code.

Comment: I hope it is true for all types ? _ctype_ is equal-to _jtype_

Comment: @program-o-steve: In general, no. Java types have pre-specified width, whereas C types don't. In other words, Java's `int` is always 32 bits, whereas C's `int` is not.

Answer (score 0):

No convertion is needed. I've used a simple static cast.

```
jfieldID varPtr = env->GetFieldID(dataClass, "var", "D");
jdouble jdoubleVar = env->GetDoubleField(dataClass, varPtr);

double varDouble = static_cast<double>(jdoubleVar);
```