# JNI trouble converting Java double to jdouble

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native-methods

I am trying to pass java `Double` to a native method in C++ which expects `double` as the input parameter. But the JNI wrapper method holds parameter as `jobject` instead of `jdouble`. Can anyone shed me some light on how to resolve this issue.

Is it possible to cast `jobject` to `jdouble`?

Comment: Removed unnecessary thanking, etc. however this question needs to be improved as it's too broad and shows no research.

Comment: Why? Why not pass it as a `double` and avoid the whole priblem?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515886/converting-jdouble-to-double-of-type-c

Comment: @EJP I wish to do it but I am not able to. Basically I created a Java class as public native double getPrice(Double price). When I converted it into .h file, it converted the method as, JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_PriceEngine_getPrice (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject); That is why I have this problem.

Comment: @EJP as I tried to explain you I realized my mistake. I was trying to pass Double instead of double which caused the issue. Thank you any way.

Comment: Your second-last comment can't be correct. If you had defined the Java native method with a `Double` parameter, the native signature would have had `jobject,` not `jdouble.` Evidently you changed the Java native method declaration after you generated the .h file. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily convert `Double` to double in C++,

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_PriceEngine_getPrice (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject price) {
    jclass jcDouble = env->FindClass("java/lang/Double");
    jmethodID jmidDoubleValue = env->GetMethodID(jcDouble, "doubleValue", "()D" );
    double dPrice = env->callDoubleMethod(jmidDoubleValue, price);
}
```

but still doing this in Java is easier.

Comment: Minor bug in the signature: should be **D**, not **J**. jmethodID jmidDoubleValue = env->GetMethodID(jcDouble, "doubleValue", "()D" );

Comment: Thanks! Now I see that somebody actually reads these answers ;-)